# Sync local and web sql

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, cordova, synchronization, indexeddb

I have a Cordova(ionic) application which using SQLite plugin as local database. Our web service is connected to MS SQL server. When user have no internet connection he should be able to add data into local DB(SQLite), then when he/she is connected to internet user need to sync to web DB(MS SQL Server).

There are 7 tables with large amount of data(~10000 rows per table). I need 100% reliability on data. Without dropping any data.

Is there any algorithm or feature to do this thing?

Which one is better in mobile? IndexedDB or SQLite.

Comment: How big is your data in KB/MB?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure about size. Application is not yet completed. Is that matters?

Comment: You're saying you want to store 10k rows * 7 tables, that's 70K rows - Of what? It makes a difference.

Comment: It is like an application which a userX use for adding and removing data from with phone when he is offline. There will be minimum 500 users like this under one domain(app). So all the users need to know the status of every entity(same entity can have different branches in different locations). So this app should completely work without internet.

All data will be text only.VARCHAR or DECIMAL. No images(as of now)

Comment: Commenting, rather than answering, as (a) it's late and (b) I don't want points for recommending something I helped build. [Zumero](http://zumero.com/) does *exactly* this (offline-friendly SQL Server / SQLite sync), and we include a Cordova plugin and samples.